# UV UDIM texture tile set scale as 1024x1024

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, texture-coordinates

Using Blender 2.90.1

I have to change my scale to 4K every time I open the file (yes I saved). Upon re-opening it goes back to 1024x1024  (*Just for the first tile*). Is this because I might have set it to 1024x1024 initally?and it wont let me change it?  Or because Blender by default wants to open the UV editor/ scaling at 1024x1024?

[image]